# Example of using a parameter passed through $state.go

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain how to use parameters sent with $state.go? In CreatePollController I create a poll which I send to the state `add_data_poll` (`AddDataPollController`), but I really don't know how to access this parameter to display it in the view or use it in the controller (I tried to see the response with `console.log($scope.response)`, but it doesn't work), can anyone explain me?

```
angular.module('estudios')

.controller('CreatePollController', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$state',
function($scope, Restangular, $state) {

  $scope.addPoll = function() {
    if ($scope.allow_anonymous_answer == null)
      $scope.allow_anonymous_answer = false

    var poll = {title: $scope.title, description: $scope.description, allow_anonymous_answer: $scope.allow_anonymous_answer, initial_message: $scope.initial_message, final_message: $scope.final_message};
    Restangular.all('polls').post(poll).then(function(response) {
      $state.go('add_data_poll', response);
    });
  };
}])

.controller('AddDataPollController', ['$scope', 'Restangular',
function($scope, Restangular) {
}]);
```

And these are the corresponding states.

```
        .state('create_poll', {
      url: '/create_poll',
            parent: 'home',
      templateUrl: 'poll/create_poll.html',
      controller: 'CreatePollController'
    })
        .state('add_data_poll', {
      url: '/create_poll/add_data_poll',
            parent: 'home',
      templateUrl: 'poll/add_data_poll.html',
      controller: 'AddDataPollController'
```

Comment: you need to specify param like url:'/create_poll/add_data_poll/:paramName', then use $state.go(..., {paramName:123}), then it will be in $stateParams

Comment: Also important that you define the parameter with default value in the state definition also. As I remember it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have either `params` defined in your state or query params defined in your state url.

Example for state `params`:

```
.state('add_data_poll', {
      url: '/create_poll/add_data_poll',
      params: {
          // define object with parameters that you want to pass
          // Example:
          id: 1 // 1 is the default parameter if no id is passed
      }    
      parent: 'home',
      templateUrl: 'poll/add_data_poll.html',
      controller: 'AddDataPollController'
```

This way you can send parameters but they won't be available in the query string and upon refresh they will be lost.

Example for defining query parameters:

```
.state('add_data_poll', {
          url: '/create_poll/add_data_poll?someParameter&anotherOne',  
          parent: 'home',
          templateUrl: 'poll/add_data_poll.html',
          controller: 'AddDataPollController'
```

`someParameter` and `anotherOne` will be available if you pass them from the incoming state.

When passing parameters you should define what parameters you are passing.

```
$state.go('some.route', {id: 2, someParam: 'coolParam');
```

And then you can access them with `$stateParams` in the controller. But first you need to inject it.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($stateParams) {
   console.log($stateParams);
});
```

It is not good idea to pass the whole response from an API. Better will be if you choose just the stuff you need from the response and build your state around them.

Read more about `ui-router` `state` `params` [**HERE**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: Thank you!, it worked!, but correct the part `myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($stateParams)...` with `myApp.controller('myCtrl', '$stateParams', function($stateParams)...` Although it may be obvious, I'm a total noob in AngularJS.